# Roll levels of a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Suppose I have a dataframe where my columns are a MultiIndex

```
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [[1, 2], ['A', 'B'], ['First', 'Second']],
    names=['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird']
)
dat = np.arange(16).reshape(2, -1)
df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=col)
df

Cat      1                         2                    
Dog      A            B            A            B       
Bird First Second First Second First Second First Second
0        0      1     2      3     4      5     6      7
1        8      9    10     11    12     13    14     15
```

---

I want to adjust the columns such that the `Bird` level is on top, `Cat` level shifts down to the middle, and `Dog` goes to the bottom.

#### Attempt 1

Using `swaplevel` can be used in succession but feels clumsy to create a whole dataframe in the middle just to augment the columns.

```
df.swaplevel(0, 2, 1).swaplevel(1, 2, 1).sort_index(1)

Bird First             Second            
Cat      1       2          1       2    
Dog      A   B   A   B      A   B   A   B
0        0   2   4   6      1   3   5   7
1        8  10  12  14      9  11  13  15
```

---

#### Attempt 2

Create new `MultiIndex` should be efficient but is not as intuitive and may be unnecessarily verbose.

```
def roll(x):
    return x[-1:] + x[:-1]

df.set_axis(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [roll(x) for x in df.columns.values],
        names=roll(df.columns.names)
    ), axis=1, inplace=False).sort_index(1)

Bird First             Second            
Cat      1       2          1       2    
Dog      A   B   A   B      A   B   A   B
0        0   2   4   6      1   3   5   7
1        8  10  12  14      9  11  13  15
```

---

### Question

Is there a clean and intuitive way to do this without creating an intermediate dataframe in the middle?

Comment: Was hoping this was going to be another canonical, never found a good way to do this :P

Comment: (-: nope, those are my two attempts.  This is a legit question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you need Sir ? Using [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html):

```
df.reorder_levels(['Bird','Cat','Dog'],axis=1).sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
Out[396]: 
Bird First             Second            
Cat      1       2          1       2    
Dog      A   B   A   B      A   B   A   B
0        0   2   4   6      1   3   5   7
1        8  10  12  14      9  11  13  15
```

Comment: Champion!  Yes, exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hrm... I think I could have used this on a stack overflow solution I posted a few days ago.... let's see if I can find it now. +1